# Counting rows in datagridview using c#

Tags: c#

I used following code to count datagrid rows, but it works on button only. I want the total number of rows in a textbox, but it doesn't increment itself as the number of rows increase.

```
int numRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

txtTotalItem.Text = numRows.ToString();
```

Comment: So you want the number in the textbox to change automatically when rows are added/removed rather than when you click a button? Just use the [RowsAdded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx) and [RowsRemoved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsremoved(v=vs.110).aspx) events to change the textbox.

Comment: should i use RowsAdded or RowsRemoved in textchanged property of textbox?

Comment: its  Access database

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you assign the number, the textbox will display only that number, it will not update.

You can use an event and assign the new number to the textbox.

```
dataGridView1.RowsAdded+=(s,a)=>OnRowNumberChanged;

private void OnRowNumberChanged()
{
    txtTotalItem.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
}
```

Following **Equalsk's** answer, you need to have the event for removed rows as well. You can subscribe to both events with the same function since you need to just check the number.

```
dataGridView1.RowsRemoved+=(s,a)=>OnRowNumberChanged();
```

Comment: Upvote for subscribing to both at the same time, much neater than mine

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood your question correctly you want the TextBox value to change automatically when rows are added or removed because at the moment you have to press a button to refresh. Am I right?

If so just subscribe to the [.RowsAdded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx) and [.RowsRemoved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsremoved(v=vs.110).aspx) events and update the TextBox from there.

```
dataGridView1.RowsAdded += RowsAdded;
dataGridView1.RowsRemoved += RowsRemoved;

private void RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    txtTotalItem.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
}

private void RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    txtTotalItem.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: all answers works fine but following code was generating error. and after removing that line. rest of code works as it supposed to be. dataGridView1.RowsAdded += RowsAdded;

Comment: why this code(dataGridView1.RowsRemoved+=dataGridView1_RowsRemoved;) was used because this( txtTotalItem.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString(); ) is still working even after removing that

Comment: Rows removed would update the text box if rows were removed. It might be that you never remove rows and therefore don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

the datagridview will count the last empty row so make sure to

> look for AllowUserToAddRows property of datagridview and set it to False.

Or add this to your code, in my case i used a label and i named it labelTotalResult, do this if you want to keep the property as true

```
                    labelTotalResult.Text = (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1).ToString();
```